# Автоматический выбор в Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

При запуска приложения уже был выбран определенный пункт из боковой шторки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, при загрузке уже открывалась галерея.

Comment: откорректируйте свой вопрос, пожалуйста. Что конкретно вам нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У ваc в onCreate надо вписать:

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if (navigationView != null) {
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_gallery); // ваш айдишник из activity_main_drawer
    }
```